# Populate a model from database ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following model:

```
namespace Factura.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("factura.marfa")]
    public partial class marfa
    {    
        [Key]
        public int idmarfa { get; set; }

        [StringLength(45)]
        public string denumire { get; set; }

        public int idfurnizor { get; set; } 
    } 
}
```

And I have also a class that inherits DbContext:

```
namespace Factura.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class FacturaContext : DbContext
    {
        public FacturaContext() : base("name=FacturaContext")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<marfa> marfas { get; set; }

        [...]

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

In my controller I have the following code:

```
namespace Factura.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class CumparatorController : Controller
    {
        FacturaContext dbFactura = new FacturaContext();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Cumparaturi()
        {
            var marfas = dbFactura.marfas.ToList();
            return View(marfas);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that `dbFactura.marfas` is null, it doesn't bring anything from Database even if the table is populated.

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you!

Comment: Code looks fine. How did you verify it is `null` ?

Comment: it crashed and i put a breakpoint at that line

Answer (score 0):

Remove `[Table("factura.marfa")]` from marfa class and add the following in your `OnModelCreating` in `FacturaContext`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<marfa>().ToTable("factura_marfa");  //updated . with _
```

Create the migration & run

Comment: How do I create the migration?

Comment: If you are using code first (which is obvious), go to Package Manager Console> Select the project where your `FacturaContext` exists> run the following command `add-migration changes` and then `update-database`

Comment: First time I created the migration successfully but it still didn't bring anything, but I put by mistake 'ToTable("factura.marfa")' instead of 'ToTable("factura_marfa")'. And now at 'update-database' I got an error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: OK. Better just recreate the model from scratch or search on how to create migrations. You should be able to create the migration after making the change